# set information about a property

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am making an editor that will look at javascript classes (es6), and display particular information about key properties. I wanted to try and use decorators to accomplish this, so something like this:

```
class Transform extends Component {

    @serializable
    public position: Vector3 = Vector3.zero;

}
```

Then my decorator would looks something like this:

```
function serializable(...args): any {
    let target = args[0];
    let key = args[1];
    let descriptor = args[2] || {};
    descriptor.writable = true;
    descriptor.serializable = true;
    return descriptor;
}
```

Then when I am analyzing the class I would do something like this:

```
components.forEach(comp => {
    var info = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(comp, 'position');
    if(info.serializable){
        // display in editor
    }
});
```

The issue I am having is that it will let me set additional descriptor values, but I can not access them.

What could I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit that it's not very clear [from the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators), because it states that:

> NOTE  A Property Descriptor is not provided as an argument to a
>   property decorator due to how property decorators are initialized in
>   TypeScript. This is because there is currently no mechanism to
>   describe an instance property when defining members of a prototype,
>   and **no way to observe or modify the initializer for a property. As
>   such, a property decorator can only be used to observe that a property
>   of a specific name has been declared for a class**.

But then:

> If the property decorator returns a value, it will be used as the
>   Property Descriptor for the member

So my understand was that while the function doesn't get the descriptor to change, it can "change it" by returning a descriptor like you did.
But I guess that this isn't the case as it doesn't work.

However, just below that it gives an example of how to do that using [reflect-metadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata):

```
import "reflect-metadata";

const serializableMetadataKey = "serializable";

function serializable(): any {
    return Reflect.metadata(serializableMetadataKey, true);
}

function isSerializable(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
    return Reflect.getMetadata(serializableMetadataKey, target, propertyKey);
}

class Transform extends Component {
    @serializable()
    public position: Vector3 = Vector3.zero;
}

components.forEach(comp => {
    if (isSerializable(comp, "position")) {
        // display in editor
    }
});
```